# Terminate a long-running Python command within a PyQt application

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, multiprocessing, terminate

I have a PyQt GUI which I use to start long-running computations in Python. Here's a minimal example:

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QDialog,
                             QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QDialogButtonBox)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        button = QPushButton("Start", self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.long_task)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.show()

    def long_task(self):
        dialog = QDialog(self)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(dialog)
        label = QLabel("Running...")
        button = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        vbox.addWidget(label)
        vbox.addWidget(button)
        dialog.open()
        time.sleep(10)  # long task, external function
        dialog.close()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

From the main window, I can start a task by clicking the button. Then a modal dialog pops up and the task starts. It is okay if the GUI is blocked (I know I can prevent freezing the GUI thread by putting the task in a separate worker thread, but this is not the point). Critically, I want to be able to hit the "Cancel" button to terminate the task. Alternatively, since the long-running tasks are always Python commands, I could also live with terminating the task with Ctrl+C.

I cannot change the long-running Python command: i.e. I can't break it up into tiny pieces and use a state variable in combination with threading, as is sometimes suggested. The alternative (pressing Ctrl+C) also doesn't work since PyQt doesn't seem to register it (even though the Python interpreter should while it is running the task).

Comment: You can not be helped if you do not indicate how heavy the task is, one possible option is to execute that task in another thread

Comment: What do you mean by heavy? I used `time.sleep(10)` in my example, in reality it is some Python command that performs calculations that usually take much longer. That's why I want the option to cancel this job. I don't want to do anything else in the GUI except for being able to cancel the task.

Comment: I mean if you can run without locking the GUI and stop time.sleep(10) your problem is solved, are you sure? I have seen similar problems, I have solved similar problems, but when they wanted to implement the problem it was totally different

Comment: Yes, exactly - I want the GUI to remain responsive (e.g. no spinning ball on a Mac), but the dialog window should be modal - so the only possible user interaction is either wait until `time.sleep(10)` has finished or cancel `time.sleep(10)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing). This will allow you to run a task (or group of tasks) concurrently and terminate processing at any time. However, make sure you read the [programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming) to understand how to use the module effectively. In particular, although the [terminate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate) method works fine for self-contained tasks, it should not be used with multiple tasks that use shared resources.

Here is a simple demo based on your example:

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QDialog,
                             QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QDialogButtonBox)

from multiprocessing import Pool

def long_task():
    for x in range(10):
        print('long task:', x)
        time.sleep(1)
    return 'finished'

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        button = QPushButton("Start", self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.long_task)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.show()

    def long_task(self):
        dialog = QDialog(self)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(dialog)
        label = QLabel("Running...")
        button = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        button.rejected.connect(dialog.close)
        vbox.addWidget(label)
        vbox.addWidget(button)
        def callback(msg):
            print(msg)
            dialog.accept()
        pool.apply_async(long_task, callback=callback)
        if dialog.exec_() == QDialog.Rejected:
            pool.terminate()
            print('terminated')

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great! Do you know if memory usage could be a problem with this approach? That is, what if my long task works on a large objects that occupies 2GB RAM - will this object be copied to the new process?

Comment: @cbrnr. Multiprocessing just looks for the module where the function is defined, imports that module, and then runs the code in a separate process. It should be no different than explicitly running the code as a separate script. Copying is only a problem if you pass large amounts of data as arguments in the initial call, or attempt to pass data from one process to another. Having said all that, I am no expert on the inner workings of multiprocessing, so you should just try it and see what actually happens.

Comment: After some testing I noticed that the dialog disappears only if the Cancel button is clicked (or the dialog is closed), at which point the running process is terminated. However, if the job finishes, the dialog stays visible (because its event loop is still running). How can this dialog be closed automatically once the job has finished?

Comment: @cbrnr. I thought I made that obvious by showing how to add a simple callback. Anyway, I have altered my code example to make it explicit. (PS: please remember to re-accept my answer).

Comment: Not obvious enough for me :-) - anyway, now this is perfect! Thanks!

Comment: It is worth noting that if you want to use a lambda function for the callback, it always gets the return value from the worker, so `callback=dialog.accept` doesn't work. Instead, use `callback=lambda x: dialog.accept()`.

Comment: Another minor tweak: instead of `if dialog.exec_() == QDialog.Rejected:`, you could use `if not dialog.exec_():`.

Comment: @cbrnr do not modify the code, that is a sensitive part, you could modify errors in the grammar, syntax, but not in the logic, that threatens the response. You should suggest that to the author, although I do not agree with his last suggestion, that makes the code less readable.

Comment: Unfortunately this approach doesn't work in my application (I get errors and memory consumption is excessive, see [here](https://github.com/cbrnr/mnelab/pull/15)). However, your answer is fine for the toy example.

Comment: @cbrnr. Oh well, it was worth a shot. There is no point in attempting to use any kind of thread-based approach, because python just does not support true concurrency (that is the principal reason why the `multiprocessing` module was introduced). It looks like it would be better to set up a daemon process to do the heavy lifting, and then communicate with the gui using a local socket. Then you can just kill the process to terminate it. Qt's [local socket classes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocalserver.html) are quite easy to use. If necessary, you can use json to send complex messages.